# Order by date (timestamp) of 2 separate tables, with data from 2 more tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have total of 4 tables: posts_messages, private_messages, users, posts.
I want to display list of all the last messages of either posts_messages or private_messages, order by the last message sent in any of them.

The other 2 tables (users, and posts) contain data I want to display along with the last message: the "users" contain the name of the sender, and is meant to display along with the private_messages' last message.
The posts table contains the post title, and is meant to display along the posts_messages' last message.

**`sender_id` on `private_messages` and `poster_id` on `posts_messages` are one of the `user_id` on `users`

Example output:

```
John Doe: See you  (15:05)
Post Title #1: Great idea (14:55)
Post Title #4: Looking good (13:20)
Albert Stein: later Yes, sure..(12:00)
```

So I will need to fetch rows 24 and 25 from private_messages and rows 10 and 11 from posts_message, and order them by date

(**What's important is not the concatenation itself ( I can later add this, so I can select all fields) - the important part is to only get single row of message without duplication as you can see below: There are multiple messages but you only get the last one from each different message)

The tables looks like:

private_messages:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| message_id | sender_id |  receiver_id  | message_text |   date              |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   22       |      20   |      44       |   Ok got it  |2018-04-27 10:03:47  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   23       |      13   |      44       |   Very well  |2018-04-27 11:49:33  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   24       |      20   |      44       |  Yes, sure.. |2018-04-27 12:00:15  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   25       |      13   |      44       | See you later|2018-04-27 15:05:30  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

users:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| user_id |     first_name    |    last_name     |
--------------------------------------------------
|   13    |     John          |    Doe           |
--------------------------------------------------
|   20    |     Albert        |    Stein         |
--------------------------------------------------
```

posts_messages:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| message_id | post_id  | poster_id | message_text |       date           |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    8       |    1     |   98      | Hello world  |  2018-04-27 12:02:22 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    9       |    4     |   123     |    Hi all    |  2018-04-27 13:11:11 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    10      |    4     |   77      | Looking good |  2018-04-27 13:20:17 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    11      |    1     |   101     | Great idea   | 2018-04-27 14:45:15  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

posts:

```
---------------------------------------------------
| post_id | post_creator_id  |    post_title      |
---------------------------------------------------
|    1    |       22         |    Post Title #1   |
---------------------------------------------------
|    4    |       35         |    Post Title #4   |
---------------------------------------------------
```

Hope this is understandable post,
A bit complicated, hopefully can be done
Thanks!

Comment: which query have you tried?

Comment: you will have to join the tables. Please give more information so we can help you out. Thanks.

Comment: The example outoup doesnt have any column name, we dont know what fields you are displaying. Also include some sample data in the tables to match your desire output.

Comment: Provide some sample data and expect result. that really help

Comment: Data provided. Devsi Odedra, I had earlier a join with only 2 separate tables (the messages and users) but when I wanted to add the other 2 tables I had no idea which query to try

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for the post table.   This should show the latest message for each post.   I think that's what you want.

```
select  post_messages.*
from    post_messages,
        (
            select    max(message_id),
                      post_id
            from      post_messages
            group by  post_id  -- the greater the message id, the newer the message.  You can use date to too if you want, will run slower.
         ) as post_latest_view
where   post_messages.message_id = post_latest_view.message_id;
```

Comment: I already have for single table (I have it for the posts too) but the problem is combining all 4 together

Answer (score 0):

Using `UNION ALL` combine `private_messages` and `posts_messages` then `ORDER BY DATE`

- `CONCAT` function can combine your message and message_title
- `date_format(DATE,'(%H:%i)')` get `hh:mm` dateformat

You can try this.

```
  SELECT content FROM (
    SELECT CONCAT(u.first_name,' ',u.last_name,':',pm.message_text,' (',date_format(DATE,'%H:%i'),')') content,DATE 
    FROM private_messages pm
    INNER JOIN users u on u.user_id = pm.sender_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT(p.post_title,':',pm.message_text,' (',date_format(DATE,'%H:%i'),')'),DATE 
    FROM posts_messages pm
    INNER JOIN posts p on p.post_id=pm.post_id

)t
ORDER BY DATE DESC
```

*sqlfiddle:https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nL5apRJ8pWVqDQuFzH5pp7/1*

```
SELECT CONCAT(message_title,'：',message_Content) content
FROM (
    SELECT CONCAT(u.first_name,' ',u.last_name) message_title,CONCAT(pm.message_text,date_format(DATE,'(%H:%i)')) as 'message_Content',DATE 
    FROM private_messages pm
    INNER JOIN users u on u.user_id = pm.sender_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  p.post_title,CONCAT(pm.message_text,date_format(DATE,'(%H:%i)')) message_content,DATE 
    FROM posts_messages pm
    INNER JOIN posts p on p.post_id=pm.post_id
)t
ORDER BY DATE DESC
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b255c5/8*

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Sorry that I didn't make it clear in the post: But I updated the post with more data: The important part is not the concatenation itself, I can simply select all fields and later add the names/ titles. The important is that if there is more than 1 row for each post / private message: get only 1 distinct row (I added data in the post - so you see private messages and posts messages now contain more rows, but select only the last distinct of each without duplications)

Comment: @pileup How about this query?http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a3d1a7/16
Getting the `MAX(message_id)` on subquery `Self Join` itself then `UNION ALL`them

Comment: The problem is that I need only the rows, without the concatenation part ( I will later concat using PHP) so in your example, I get undefined indexes. Your fiddle is working, but I need instead to get only the rows with all fields. so in this example I need rows 25 and 24 from private_messages and rows 11 and 10 from posts_messages and order them by DESC, I will later concat fields with PHP (Your example is basically the answer, only I need the rows with all fields)

Comment: Here is sample, without the concatenation part http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a3d1a7/19. I think you need to provide your PHP Code,or show us what's your expect result from thoes data from your PHP Code read from mysql.

Comment: So in the PHP code I will check whether the result is from post_messages or private_messages and I will do "while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))" to get all rows and display with the correct information (if it's post, then a prefix "Post title:" and if it's a private message a prefix "First name + Last name:"

Comment: How did you use `$row` when you read the data?I think you could read the date by column name from query result set.http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: You can refer this How to read aliases on MySQL. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932205/getting-column-value-when-sql-query-has-aliases

Comment: So I think I have basic misunderstanding: The fiddle above, actually creates sort of new table and then I need to do another SELECT to select the correct column with their new aliases?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169986/discussion-between-pileup-and-d-shih).

Answer (score 0):

Try this (might need a small debug since I don't have mySQL installed):

```
select line from(
    ( select CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name, ': ', p.message_text, ' (', 
    DATE_FORMAT(p.date, '%H:%i'), ')') as line, p.date as date from users u, 
    private_messages p where u.user_id = p.sender_id ) 

    UNION

    ( select CONCAT(po.post_title, ': ', m.message_text, ' (', 
    DATE_FORMAT(m.date, '%H:%i'), ')') as line, m.date as date from 
    posts_messages m, posts po where po.post_id = m.post_id )

    order by date DESC
)
```

Comment: Sorry that I didn't make it clear in the post: But I updated the post with more data: The important part is not the concatenation itself, I can simply select all fields and later add the names/ titles. The important is that if there is more than 1 row for each post / private message: get only 1 distinct row (I added data in the post - so you see private messages and posts messages now contain more rows, but select only the last distinct of each without duplications)